# Cannot save Eclipse debug configuration as shared file

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm creating a debug configuration for a new project. When I create it with Save as option set to Local file everything works fine.

But since I want to share the configuration via SVN I need to keep it as a file under the project directory so I change Save as to Shared file (with the default directory at project root). The configuration file appears on the hard drive as expected and debug works OK but after I restart Eclipse there is no debug configuration in the project and when I try to debug I get a message Launch configuration trunk CODS-MR at file:/home/saguna/workspace/trunk/MR.launch does not exist. although the file itself present and appears to have valid contents.

What seems to be the problem?

Thanks.